# Add image before all a href tags. works but not inline

Tags: html, css

This should be easy but can't figure it out.

I'm adding an image icon to all a tags:

```
a.textLink:before{
content: "";
background: url("../img/plus-button.png") no-repeat;    
background-size:contain;
display: block;
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
float: left;
margin: -6px 6px 0 0;}
}
```

My HTML is just 2 links inline:

```
<a class="textLink" href="#">Link 1</a>  <a class="textLink clearFloat" href="#">Link 2</a>
```

The problem is, both "plus-buytton.png" images float left, so they aren't inserting before each link but together.

Answer (score 0):

remove `float:left;` and add `display:inline-block, vertical-align:middle;`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
a.textLink:before{
content: url("http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/24x24-free-button-icons-by-aha-soft/png/24x24/user-admin.png");
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<a class="textLink" href="#">Link 1</a>  <a class="textLink clearFloat" href="#">Link 2</a>
```